# Pthread - setting scheduler parameters

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I wanted to use read-writer locks from pthread library in a way, that writers have priority over readers. I read in my man pages that

> If the Thread Execution Scheduling option is supported, and the threads involved      in the lock are executing with the scheduling policies SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR,      the  calling  thread shall not acquire the lock if a writer holds the lock      or if writers of higher or equal priority are blocked on the lock;      otherwise, the calling thread shall acquire the lock.

so I wrote small function that sets up thread scheduling options.

```
void thread_set_up(int _thread)
{
 struct sched_param *_param=malloc(sizeof (struct sched_param));
 int *c=malloc(sizeof(int));
 *c=sched_get_priority_min(SCHED_FIFO)+1;
 _param->__sched_priority=*c;
 long *a=malloc(sizeof(long));
 *a=syscall(SYS_gettid);
 int *b=malloc(sizeof(int));
 *b=SCHED_FIFO;
 if (pthread_setschedparam(*a,*b,_param) == -1)
 {
    //depending on which thread calls this functions, few thing can happen
    if (_thread == MAIN_THREAD)
        client_cleanup();
    else if (_thread==ACCEPT_THREAD)
    {
        pthread_kill(params.main_thread_id,SIGINT);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
}
```

}

sorry for those `a,b,c` but I tried to `malloc` everything, still I get `SIGSEGV` on the call to `pthread_setschedparam`, I am wondering why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if these are the exact causes of your problems but they should help you hone in on it.

(1) `pthread_setschedparam` returns a 0 on success and a positive number otherwise.  So

```
if (pthread_setschedparam(*a,*b,_param) == -1)
```

will never execute.  It should be something like:

```
if ((ret = pthread_setschedparam(*a, *b, _param)) != 0)
{ //yada yada 
}
```

As an aside, it isn't 100% clear what you are doing but `pthread_kill` looks about as ugly a way to do it as possible.

(2) `syscall(SYS_gettid)` gets the OS threadID.  `pthread__setschedparam` expects the *pthreads thread id*, which is different.  The pthreads thread id is returned by `pthread_create` and `pthread_self` in the datatype `pthread_t`. Change the `pthread__setschedparam` to use this type and the proper values instead and see if things improve.

(3) You need to run as a priviledge user to change the schedule.  Try running the program as root or sudo or whatever.

Comment: 1. pthread_kill is to notify main thread that other one encountered fatal error, I overrided signal handler for sigint to perform cleanup

Comment: 2. you were right about syscall and pthread_self, I changed passing parameter to pthread_self and it worked 3.also you are right here. I thank you very much for help.